# Configure Send Blackout Window for Mobile Messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

I want to configure a Send Blackout Window to prevent Mobile Messages to be sent at night. I use Journey Builder to send these Mobile Messages.

While SF recommend to configure the Send Blackout Window directly in Mobile Connect, I don't know exactly where I must set up this functionnality. In addition to that, what happens after the blackout window? Are mobile messages still sent out?

Thanks a lot for your insigths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the Send Blackout under Administration in MobileConnect:

In Administration,

- click Set Blackout Window.

  Change the status to Enabled.

  Set the beginning and end of the send blackout.

  Save the  send blackout.

**What happens after the blackout window?**

> If your send starts at 9 PM and takes two hours, and your send
>   blackout starts at 10 PM, the send continues until 11 PM, into the
>   send blackout time period.

**Are mobile messages still sent out?** --> YES

***Important notes:***

Note 1:

> Set the Send Blackout in MobileConnect and not in Journey Builder.

Note 2:

> In Journey Builder, a send blackout window completely prevents
>   messages from sending. Messages don’t queue for sending at later time.

**References:**

- [Send Blackouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_send_blackouts.htm&type=5)
- [Set a Send Blackout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_set_a_send_blackout.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks @Rachid Mamai. 
Once I configured the Blackout Window, does it apply to one or all of the Mobile Messages?

Comment: Sorry to bother, I have another question. Does Send Blackout Window apply to Mobile Messages in Journey Builder? In other words, do I have to re-configure the Blackout Window in my journey?

Comment: Blackout Window applies for all sends except the ones conducted using MobileConnect API. For your second question, to be honest I did not test this case, I'll suggest that you set the Blackout Window in MobileConnect and try to send an SMS through a Journey without setting the Blackout Window in it..

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks again!